# How can I insert a row into MSSQL with PHP using a lookup table?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm creating a web application and one of the database interfaces requires a lookup table. This is the part which executes SQL:

```
$A = $_POST['A'];
$B = $_POST['B'];

$tsql= "INSERT INTO INSERT_TABLE (
            A,
            B_Index)
            VALUES
            (?, ?)";
$var = array($A, $B);
```

My problem is that I don't want to insert the value of B itself, but the index of the value in a lookup table. I tried to join the VALUES row with the table, but MSSQL doesn't seem to like that. Any ideas?

EDIT: The lookup table would have the form:

```
index | value
-------------
   1  |  horse
   2  |   cow
  ... |  ...
```

If $B == 'horse', I would want to insert 2 instead of 'horse'.

EDIT2: I tried this query, but unfortunately it does not work, but it shows what I want to do:

```
INSERT INTO INSERT_TABLE (A, B_Index)
VALUES 
SELECT temp.A, LT.index
FROM (A,B) temp
INNER JOIN LOOKUP_TABLE LT
ON LT.value = temp.B
```

Comment: Can you please more clarify your query....

Comment: I added some extra information. Does that clarify things, or is it still not clear?

Comment: Every-time there is "B" at start in column2?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. The lookup table wouldn't actually have values b1, b2, etc, those are just placeholder variables.

Comment: What is the meaning of '2' which you want to insert in place of 'horse'?

Comment: Its the primary key of the value 'horse'.

Comment: Then first you have to check for 'horse' in `table2` and get the unique id of that row, and that unique ID will store in `table1`.

Comment: Can you please add your both table with structure, so we can suggest you how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the SELECT and FROM clauses in your INSERT statements.  This allows you pull records from your LOOKUP_TABLE into your INSERT_TABLE.

**Example**

```
INSERT INTO INSERT_TABLE
    (
        A,
        B
    )
SELECT
    ?,
    lt.Value
FROM
    LOOKUP_TABLE AS lt
WHERE
    lt.Index = ?
;
```

**EDIT:** I really should have highlighted that the above is pseudocode.  In practice the question marks should be replaced with values.  See the comment from @Terminus below for more on this.

Comment: Looks like what I need, but it seems that MS SQL doesn't like the ? in the code. Is it some kind of wildcard variable? I'll try to find something similar for MS SQL.

Comment: I've included the ?s as placeholders for your variables.  You will need to parameterise these from PHP.

Comment: @BallzofFury That is a wild card. If you use prepared statements, you can pass an array of variables when you execute the query and it'll work. Show your php code to get a more detailed answer.

Comment: @Terminus, I'm sorry, wasn't thinking in terms of PHP. I'm familiar with those kind of wildcards, and after a little work I've got it functioning properly in my code. Thanks a lot!